# Why I can't create use and grant privileges in MySQL

Tags: mysql

There is a problem in my MySQL server.

When I want to create user or grant privileges, The error below occur

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
```

but When I execute command

```
use databases;
```

It can be executed correctly

I don't do any configurations of MySQL and the version of MySQL is 5.6.22, OS is RHEL 5.6 x86_64.

Can anybody tell me why it happened and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried everything on this list?: [B.5.2.9 MySQL server has gone away](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/gone-away.html)

Comment: please check error description in mysql errorlog file as this error message is very common for different issues...

Comment: thanks and I figured it out